# How To Add GeometryProxy To PreviewProvider

Tags: swiftui

Okay so I am passing in GeometryProxy into a struct view body and I have no idea how to do this and still use PreviewProvider can someone please help me with this?

```
struct MyView: View {

    let geometry: GeometryProxy

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           .... More Code Here
        }
    }
}

struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            // This is where Im having trouble. I have no idea how to pass in GeometryProxy
            MyView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you don't need to pass the geometry proxy as they'll have the same geometry. That should be enough:

```
struct MyView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryProxy { proxy in
           VStack {
              .... More Code Here
           }
        }
    }
}
```

But, if you really want to pass the geometry, you can do this:

```
struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        GeometryProxy {
            MyView(proxy: proxy)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple , Ive been up for too long LOL. The second answer definitely did it. I still have to pass it in as far as I know right now. I may edit this in the near future to make it work without having to pass GeometryProxy in. For now if I try to wrap it then I have problems with my ScrollView. But anyway, thanks, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Great! Yes, geometry reader takes all the space and creates other problems - so personally I try to avoid it as much as I can. Good luck!

Comment: I may take your advice on that. You are correct, it has helped a little as far as scalability but it has caused so many other issues in the process. Thanks again. You have been awesome.

Comment: I am glad, anytime @JoeAlvini 

Answer (score 9):

It should like this:

```
struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            MyView(proxy: proxy)
        }
     }
 }
```